# Change magento default grid error message

Tags: grid

I am making a custom grid for my extension and I wish to change the default error message that is being displayed when we select any massaction but we donot select any checkbox.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `_prepareMassaction` method of your grid block add this line:

```
$this->getMassactionBlock()
     ->setErrorText(
         Mage::helper('core')->jsQuoteEscape(
             Mage::helper('your_helper_alias')->__('Your message here')
         )
     );
```

Comment: Man!! how you find this stuff quickly

Comment: @Bhupendra. I had to do the same thing some time ago.

Comment: So where did you find it ... i tried to find it on google and core but i found it in abstract class.  so i thought you have some magic trick :D

Comment: @Bhupendra. Look for the default text in the core files. [You will find it here](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Massaction/Abstract.php#L52). This means you can access it from the mass action block.  And in any grid block your can access the mass action block with `$this->getMassactionBlock()`. There is already a call to that block to `_prepareMassaction`, so I thought it can be placed in there.